# how to use every even column for the corresponding odd column and create a new data frame - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read a huge Excel file where each even column (e.g., 0,2) is the number of days, and the next column is a location. Each location has a different length. As a small example, here's a sample data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


data = {
    'Unnamed: 0': [1.8, 2, 5.9],
    'Location A': [0.2, 0.3, 0.87],
    'Unnamed: 2': [6, 7],
    'Location B': [1.5, 2.0],
    'Unnamed: 4': [11],
    'Location C': [],
    'Unnamed: 6': [16.7, 17, 18, 19.6, 26,72.9],
    'Location D': [3.5, 4.0, 5.5, 6.0, 7.5, 8.0]
}

max_len = max([len(v) for v in data.values()])

for key in data.keys():
    if len(data[key]) < max_len:
        data[key].extend([np.nan] * (max_len - len(data[key])))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Since even columns do not have a header, they are saved as `Unnamed` when I use `pd.read_excel`. I would like to convert this into a new data frame with the following logic. Let `date_value = pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01', format='%Y-%m-%d')`.

The first column is the name of the location, the second column is `date_value + timedelta(days=days_to_add)` where days_to_add is the values in the Unnamed column, and the third column is the values under Location column.

```
Location A 2023-01-02 0.2
Location A 2023-01-03 0.3
Location A 2023-01-06 0.87
...

Location D 2023-03-12 8
```

Comment: Do you want to keep `Location C`, where there is no date/data?

Comment: Yes, I should have at least one row for each location. So that I can perform a proper analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unstack` with `assign`:

```
(df.iloc[:, 1::2].rename_axis(columns='Localtion').unstack()
   .reset_index(level=0, name='value')
   .assign(date=df.iloc[:,::2].mul(pd.Timedelta('1D')).add(date_value).unstack().to_numpy())
   .dropna(subset=['value','date'], how='all')
)
```

Output:

```
    Localtion  value                date
0  Location A   0.20 2023-01-02 19:12:00
1  Location A   0.30 2023-01-03 00:00:00
2  Location A   0.87 2023-01-06 21:36:00
0  Location B   1.50 2023-01-07 00:00:00
1  Location B   2.00 2023-01-08 00:00:00
0  Location C    NaN 2023-01-12 00:00:00
0  Location D   3.50 2023-01-17 16:48:00
1  Location D   4.00 2023-01-18 00:00:00
2  Location D   5.50 2023-01-19 00:00:00
3  Location D   6.00 2023-01-20 14:24:00
4  Location D   7.50 2023-01-27 00:00:00
5  Location D   8.00 2023-03-14 21:36:00
```

Comment: Just for future reference, if I want to ignore Location C, how should I modify the code?

Comment: chain that with `.loc[lambda x: x['Location'] != 'Location C']`?

Comment: Sorry what I meant is that if I want to ignore locations without data assuming that I have thousands of different location.

Comment: change `dropna(subset=['value', 'date'])` to `dropna(subset=['value'])`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = (pd.concat([df.iloc[:, 1::2].rename_axis(columns='Location')
                    .unstack().reset_index(0, name='value'),
                  pd.to_timedelta(df.iloc[:, 0::2].unstack()
                                    .droplevel(0), unit='D'
                                 ).add(date_value).rename('date')
                    
                 ], axis=1)
         .dropna(subset='value')
      )
```

Output:

```
     Location  value                date
0  Location A   0.20 2023-01-02 19:12:00
1  Location A   0.30 2023-01-03 00:00:00
2  Location A   0.87 2023-01-06 21:36:00
0  Location B   1.50 2023-01-07 00:00:00
1  Location B   2.00 2023-01-08 00:00:00
0  Location D   3.50 2023-01-17 16:48:00
1  Location D   4.00 2023-01-18 00:00:00
2  Location D   5.50 2023-01-19 00:00:00
3  Location D   6.00 2023-01-20 14:24:00
4  Location D   7.50 2023-01-27 00:00:00
5  Location D   8.00 2023-03-14 21:36:00
```

Comment: I am receiving ````TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'value' was passed````

Comment: This is because you have an older pandas version, change `.dropna(subset='value')` to `.dropna(subset=['value'])`